# Phonebook database design

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-design

I am designing database for web base(ASP.NET) Phone-book - Contact manager software.

Each contact may has different phone types .. (Home , Work , Mobile ,etc ...)
here is my database design :
[image]
Phone type contains for example :

- Home
- Work
- Emergency 
  or anything user wants.

M
 Is this well design ?

I think I'll have problem with this design that I can't displaying contacts with all their numbers (I mean each contact with all his numbers in one row not per number of contact one row) In a grid  to user.
What is your suggestion ?

I've to display all contacts with all Phone Types In a grid. 
I think I'll have problem to do that with current design .

Comment: You would be able to do that with a (slightly messy) stored procedure. The design itself is very clean, and I can't think of a design where you'd be able to organize all phone numbers in a grid pattern with a simple SQL query without knowing all `PhoneType`s in advance.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

> I think I'll have problem with this design that I can't displaying
>   contacts with all their numbers In a grid to user. What is your
>   suggestion ?

You can do that with a simple query.

```
select c.contactid, c.contactname,
       pt.typetitle,
       pn.phoneno
from contact c
inner join phonenumber pn on pn.contactid = c.contactid
inner join phonetype pt on pt.phonetypeid = pn.phonetype
```

For data integrity, you're going to need some UNIQUE constraints in addition to your primary key constraints. If I were you, I'd consider UNIQUE constraints on ContactName, TypeTitle, and the pair (ContactID, PhoneType). In fact, the pair (ContactID, PhoneType) is probably a better primary key than PhoneID; consider dropping PhoneID entirely.

Comment: I tried your query. For example if contact with name John has three numbers your query returns three rows but I've to display Contact phones in one row .
I edited last row of my question I thinks its more clear now

Comment: You can use PIVOT, but since your users can add whatever categories they like, you can't guarantee you'll produce a row that won't require horizontal scrolling. Your lives become easier if you can change this requirement.